# Accessing method inside nested instances

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I'm trying to update a PyQt label at regular time but since the label is created inside another class instance `__init__` I can't figure out how to do on my own.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer,QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
import sys


class Main(QMainWindow): #01 THIS IS THE MAIN WINDOW

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640,480))
        self.tabs_widget = Tabs(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs_widget)


class Tabs(QWidget): #02 SPLIT MAIN WINDOW TO TABS

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabOne(), "TabOne")

        self.textOne = QLabel("Text One - to be changed")
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.textOne)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def updateTextOne(self):
        self.textOne.setText("Text One - already changed")


class TabOne(QWidget): #03 TAB ONE
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.textTwo = QLabel("Text Two to be changed")
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.textTwo)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    #THIS IS THE METHOD I WOULD LIKE TO ACCESS!!!
    def updateTextTwo(self):
        self.textTwo.setText("Text Two - already changed")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(main.tabs_widget.updateTextOne)
    timer.start(2000)

    #CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO ACCESS CLASS TabOne > UpdateTextTwo()
    # timer = QTimer()
    # timer.timeout.connect(main.tabs_widget.tabWidget.)
    # timer.start(2000)


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are two Qlabels, 'textOne' is placed inside Tabs class, I can update it by running `updateTextOne()` from `if __name__ == "__main__":`

I can't figure out how to access `updateTextTwo()` method however, it is located into another class TabOne which instance is created in the previous class Tabs `__init__`.

Another questions: is there a better way to reach those methods. This is only the beginning of the project but those nested instances already make the project too complex for my programming skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store it in `Tabs()` instance here:

```
self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
self.tab_one = TabOne()
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_one, "TabOne")
```

And call:

```
main.tabs_widget.tab_one.updateTextTwo()
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

see [widget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#widget) function:

```
timer2 = QTimer()
timer2.timeout.connect(main.tabs_widget.tabWidget.widget(0).updateTextTwo)
timer2.start(2000)
```

(This only works because the widget is already stored in the `QTabWidget` and you can access it using the `widget` function. Sanyas solution is the more general solution.)

Comment: That also works! Is there any benefits of using widget() approach over instancing the inner-class?

Comment: @SvetlozarDraganov By using a member variable there are two object references in the `QTabWidget` object, which is unnecessary. If you want to delete the widget you have to delete both for example.

Comment: Very useful to know. Thank you very much again!